# AC_LANG_PROGRAM failed the linker stage because of order of linker option

Tags: c++, autotools, autoconf

I am trying to test a C++ library and have to do a little more than the AC_SEARCH_LIBS or AC_CHECK_LIB.  However, my linker is picky about the order of the options (g++ version 5.4.0).

My configure.ac contains the following code:

```
AC_LINK_IFELSE(
      [AC_LANG_PROGRAM([#include <api/BamReader.h>],  [BamTools::BamReader dummy])],
      [TEST_LIBS=="$TEST_LIBS -lbamtools"] [HAVE_BAMTOOLS=1],
      [AC_MSG_WARN([libbamtools is not installed])])
```

I know that the Bamtools are install on my system.  This will generate an negative result:

```
checking api/BamReader.h usability... yes
checking api/BamReader.h presence... no
configure: WARNING: api/BamReader.h: accepted by the compiler, rejected by the preprocessor!
configure: WARNING: api/BamReader.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for api/BamReader.h... yes
configure: WARNING: libbamtools is not installed <-- this line
```

After some investigation, it appears to be the order of the linker option.

The conftest.cpp file looks like the following:

```
#include <api/BamReader.h>
int main () {
   BamTools::BamReader dummy;
   return 0;
}
```

The autoconf macro is calling

```
g++ -o conftest -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include/bamtools -L/usr/local/lib/bamtools -lbamtools conftest.cpp/tmp/ccZiV1J9.o: In function `main':
/home/kzhou/coding/tmp/conftest.cpp:24: undefined reference to `BamTools::BamReader::BamReader()'
/home/kzhou/coding/tmp/conftest.cpp:24: undefined reference to `BamTools::BamReader::~BamReader()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If yo switch the order by putting the -lbamtools to the end, then the linker is happy:

```
g++ -o conftest -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include/bamtools -L/usr/local/lib/bamtools conftest.cpp -lbamtools
```

I wonder the AC_LANG_PROGRAM needs to be updated?  Please comment.  So far I have not found a good solution for this problem.
Please reference:

https://nerdland.net/2009/07/detecting-c-libraries-with-autotools/

Comment: As Diego pointed out, LDFLAGS will be put in front of the object or source code and LIBS will be put after.  My main mistake is the usage of these two variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like you are passing the library in the wrong variable; if you were passing the library in `LIBS` it would be in the right position because autoconf does the right thing.

Now, the code you pasted has a syntax error too (using `==` which is a comparison instead of `=` which is an assignment), and a logical one since `TEST_LIBS` was a variable used by the specific post you reference. So that is not what is setting `-lbamtools` in any of the orders.

```
save_LIBS=$LIBS
LIBS="$LIBS -lbamtools"
AC_LINK_IFELSE(
      [AC_LANG_PROGRAM([#include <api/BamReader.h>],  [BamTools::BamReader dummy])],
      [save_LIBS="$LIBS"; HAVE_BAMTOOLS=1],
      [AC_MSG_WARN([libbamtools is not installed])])
LIBS=$save_LIBS
```

this should do what you're looking for, although it's still a bit more complicated than it could be. You could use [`AC_CHECK_TYPE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.65/html_node/Generic-Types.html#Generic-Types) to just check if `BamTools::BamReader` is defined.

Comment: Diego, Thanks.  It is so hard to learn autotools; there is no good books, and the documentation is very limited.  Moreover, not so many people have mastered autotools.  I have to learn in bits and pieces.

Comment: There is John Calcote's Autotools and my Autotools Mythbuster but the latter only has pointed fix to known issues, rather than having a full explanation.

Comment: I have read John Calcote's book.  Its very good and gave me an understanding of the whole system.  The second edition of this book should add some C++ examples.